# Make method parameters Unqualified

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, wsdl, wcf-binding

Dears,
I am trying to build a WCF web service
I have a web method with list of parameters

as the code below:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://com.mwafaqat.update.ws")]
public interface UpdateAcceptanceService
{
    [OperationContract]
    updateAcceptanceStatusResponse updateAcceptanceStatus(
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://com.mwafaqat.update.ws", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]string transactionId,
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://com.mwafaqat.update.ws", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]string nationalId,
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://com.mwafaqat.update.ws", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]status status,
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://com.mwafaqat.update.ws", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]string rejectionReason,
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://com.mwafaqat.update.ws", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]DateTime requestDate,
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://com.mwafaqat.update.ws", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]DateTime updatedDate);
}

public updateAcceptanceStatusResponse updateAcceptanceStatus(
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://com.mwafaqat.update.ws", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]string transactionId,
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://com.mwafaqat.update.ws", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]string nationalId,
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://com.mwafaqat.update.ws", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]status status,
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://com.mwafaqat.update.ws", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]string rejectionReason,
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://com.mwafaqat.update.ws", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]DateTime requestDate,
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://com.mwafaqat.update.ws", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]DateTime updatedDate)
    {
        // Business Logic code goes here
    }
```

I am getting the below xml based on the above code:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://com.mwafaqat.update.ws">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <com:updateAcceptanceStatus>
         
         <com:transactionId>?</com:transactionId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <com:nationalId>?</com:nationalId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <com:status>?</com:status>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <com:rejectionReason>?</com:rejectionReason>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <com:requestDate>?</com:requestDate>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <com:updatedDate>?</com:updatedDate>
      </com:updateAcceptanceStatus>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to make the parameter Unqualified but it is not working

I need the request to be as below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://com.mwafaqat.update.ws">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <com:updateAcceptanceStatus>
         <transactionId></transactionId>
         <nationalId></nationalId>
         <status></status>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <rejectionReason></rejectionReason>
         <requestDate></requestDate>
         <updatedDate></updatedDate>
      </com:updateAcceptanceStatus>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

EDIT #1
I tried this

```
   [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://com.mwafaqat.update.ws")]
    public interface UpdateAcceptanceService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        updateAcceptanceStatusResponse updateAcceptanceStatus(
            [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]string transactionId,
            [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]string nationalId,
            [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]status status,
            [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]string rejectionReason,
            [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]DateTime requestDate,
            [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]DateTime updatedDate);

    }
```

but still if is send the request unqualified the values not set to the parameters (all parameters values are null)

Comment: `com` is namespace prefix. Remove `Namespace = "http://com.mwafaqat.update.ws"` from the parameters.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov i made this but still not working 

I tried Like this
[XmlElement( Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]string transactionId,
and like This
[XmlElement(Namespace = "", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]string transactionId,

Also

[XmlElement(Namespace = null, Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]string transactionId,

All of them not working

Comment: Have you used IDispatchMessageFormatter? According to the code you provided, I have tested and found that my SOAP message is different from your SOAP message. My SOAP message is  "< s: envelope", but your SOAP message is "< soapenv:Envelope ".